Vectorize objects in python Jax
I am unsure what is the best way to vectorize objects in Python Jax.
In particular, I want to write a code that handles both calling a method from a single instantiation of a class and from multiple (vectorized) instantiations of the class.
In the following, I write a simple example of what I would like to achieve.
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax.random as random


class Dummy:

    def __init__(self, x, key):
        self.x = x
        self.key = key

    def to_pytree(self):
        return (self.x, self.key), None

    def get_noisy_x(self):
        self.key, subkey = random.split(self.key)
        return self.x + random.normal(subkey, self.x.shape)

    @staticmethod
    def from_pytree(auxiliary, pytree):
        return Dummy(*pytree)


jax.tree_util.register_pytree_node(Dummy,
                                   Dummy.to_pytree,
                                   Dummy.from_pytree)

The class Dummy contains some information, x and keys, and has a method, get_noisy_x. The following code works as expected:
key = random.PRNGKey(0)
dummy = Dummy(jnp.array([1., 2., 3.]), key)
dummy.get_noisy_x()

I would like get_noisy_x to work also on a vectorized version of the object Dummy.
key = random.PRNGKey(0)
key, subkey = random.split(key)
key_batch = random.split(subkey, 100)
dummy_vmap = jax.vmap(lambda x: Dummy(jnp.array([1., 2., 3.]), x))(key_batch)

I would expect dummy_vmap to be an array of Dummy objects; however, instead, dummy_vmap results to be only one Dummy with vectorized x and key. This is not ideal for me because that modifies the behavior of the code. For example, if I call dummy_vmap.get_noisy_x(), I get returned an error saying that self.key, subkey = random.split(self.key) does not work because self.key is not a single key. While this error could be solved in several ways - and actually, in this example, vectorization is not really needed, my goal is to understand how to write code in a object-oriented way, that both handles correctly
dummy = Dummy(jnp.array([1., 2., 3.]), key)
dummy.get_noisy_x()

and
vectorized_dummy = .... ? 
vectorized_dummy.get_noisy_x()

Notice that the example that I have made could work in several ways without involving vectorization. What I look for, however, is a more generic way to deal with vectorization in much more complicated scenarios.
Update
I have found out that I need to vectorize get_noisy_x as well.
dummy_vmap = jax.vmap(lambda x: Dummy(jnp.array([1., 2., 3.]), x))(key_batch)
jax.vmap(lambda self: Dummy.get_noisy_x(self))(dummy_vmap) # this function call works exactly as expected.

However, this solution seems a bit counter-intuitive, and not really scalable, as in a larger project I would need to vectorize all functions of interest.


I would expect dummy_vmap to be an array of Dummy objects; however, instead, dummy_vmap results to be only one Dummy with vectorized x and key.

Your expectation here is out of line with how JAX approaches vectorization: JAX uses a struct-of-arrays pattern rather than an array-of-structs pattern. This should work entirely seamlessly with your existing object, so long as you never explicitly construct a vectorized object; for example, you could do something like this:
def apply_dummy(x, key):
  return Dummy(x, key).get_noisy_x()

key = random.key(0)
key, subkey = random.split(key)
key_batch = random.split(subkey, 100)
x = jnp.array([1., 2., 3.])

out_single = apply_dummy(x, key)
print(out_single.shape)  # (3,)

out_batch = jax.vmap(apply_dummy, in_axes=(None, 0))(x, key_batch)
print(out_batch.shape)  # (100, 3)

If you want to construct a vectorized dummy object, you can do so by applying vmap to its constructor:
vectorized_dummy = jax.vmap(Dummy, in_axes=(None, 0))(x, key_batch)

However, as you found, this will not work correctly with your Dummy object as it's currently defined, because its methods are not batch-aware. The general approach here would be to modify _get_noisy_x so that it does the appropriate thing when self.key and self.x are batched. The details will depend on assumptions you want to make: for example, if both key and x have a batch dimension, do you vectorize over both simultaneously, or do you return the outer-product? The answer, and therefore the implementation, will depend on information not provided in your question.
Also, as a side note, the way this method is defined will generally be problematic in JAX:
    def get_noisy_x(self):
        self.key, subkey = random.split(self.key)
        return self.x + random.normal(subkey, self.x.shape)

The issue is that it is impure: calling the function results in mutating self in-place (changing the value of self.key). Functions with side-effects like this may not behave as you expect when used with JAX transformations like jit, vmap, or grad: for example,. For a discussion of these issues, see JAX Sharp Bits: Pure Functions.
As a demonstration of this, take a look at the value of dummy.key before and after running the code under your Update:
dummy_vmap = jax.vmap(lambda x: Dummy(jnp.array([1., 2., 3.]), x))(key_batch)
print(dummy_vmap.key)
jax.vmap(Dummy.get_noisy_x)(dummy_vmap)
print(dummy_vmap.key)  # unchanged!

The fix would be to not rely on this kind of side-effect in your code.

Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, to transform it as a pure function, I modified each method of the class to return self as well, and then, when using the method, I would do dummy, x = dummy.get_noisy_x(), which I am not sure if it is an elegant way to solve the problem or if there are better ways. I have now implemented my class by providing both vectorized and unvectorized versions of the methods... I am not very happy with the solution provided.. your solution works but calling each time the constructor defeats my effort of making the code "object oriented"...

I don’t understand your last sentence. How does needing to construct the object make it not object-oriented?
